# How todo a success message with a alert message in c#?

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm having issues with the alert box. What I'm trying to do is after I call a c# and the function works without issue it sends out a success message. But what happens is that it sends a success message in a completely new page.

```cs
public async Task<JsonResult> Upload(IList<IFormFile> files)
{
    //does my stuff 
    string msg = "Succesfully uploaded";
    return Json(new { Message = msg });
}
```

Here the script that I do.

```
function Function() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        url: "home/Upload",
        data: "hello",
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    })
}
```

Here is the view:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input asp-file="file" id="files" name="file" onchange="CallFunction('files')" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" onclick="Function"  style="display:none" />
}
```

Comment: Can you share the view(.cshtml) snippet as well.

Comment: Yeah i can share it

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change your submit button to  this

```
 <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Function()" name="Submit" id="Submit"/>
```

You can see I have changed the **type="submit" to type="button".**

Also you can remove the BeginForm syntax as you will be using ajax to submit the form

Here is the script to submit the post request

```
function Function() {

        $.ajax(
            {
                url: "/Home/Upload",
                data: "hello",
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            })

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You must post the form with Ajax. With your code the whole page will be posted to the server.

change view to this :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" ,id = "uploadForm"}))
{
    <input asp-file="file" id="files" name="file" onchange="CallFunction('files')" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" onclick="Function"  style="display:none" />
}
```

add section script

```
@section scripts { 
 <script>
    $("#uploadForm").submit(function(e) { // note that it's better to use form Id to select form
        e.preventDefault(); // here you stop submitting form
        uploadFile();
    });

  function uploadFile() {
    $.ajax({
      url: "home/Upload",
      data: "hello",
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: "POST",
      success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
      }
    })
  } 
  </script>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are sending wrong type of data to controller. U are sending a "string" and the url:"home/Upload" also wrong, must be url:"/home/Upload"

Answer (score 0):

```
    function Function(inputId) {
    var input = document.getElementById(inputId);
     var files = input.files;
      var formData = new FormData();

      for (var i = 0; i != files.length; i++) {
       formData.append("files", files[i]);
  }

  $.ajax(
    {
      url: "/home/Upload",
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      type: "POST",
      success: function (data) {
       alert(data);
      }
    }
  );
}
```